# UISearchBar, NSPredicate, w/ Array of Objects

Tags: objective-c, object, uisearchbar, nspredicate

I have experience with Java and Android development, and am now attempting to learn Objective-C and iPhone/iPad development. In order to help teach myself, I am re-writing an application I made for android over to iPhone.

I am now attempting to use the UISearchBar in a tableview that I have populated with names from "member" objects.  However, I am having trouble using NSPredicate to retrieve the name properties from inside the member objects that I have created, as it crashes.  I was able to create a workaround by making an entirely seperate array filled with just the names and use that with NSPredicate, but this is far from ideal and creates problems down the road.

So basically by doing this I was able to pinpoint the problem to either how I use NSPedicate  or maybe how I set my member objects in a previous class. Just to clarify, my object is properly filled when I do go into the method that uses NSPredicate so I know my objects are not just nil.

Here is my .h for my member class.

```
@interface AKPsiMember : NSObject

   #define CURRENT_STATUS @"Current"
   #define ALUMNI_STATUS @"Alumni"


    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *emailAddress;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *pledgeClass;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *major;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *phoneNum;
```

And also my TableViewController .m that contains the UISearchBar method delegates

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.firstName contains[c] %@",
                                    searchText];


    self.searchedMemberNameResults = [self.listedMembers filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

}
```

And finally the error from my stack trace

```
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AKPsiMember isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x716bbd0'
```

Comment: Have you tried just to remove SELF:
`@"firstName contains[c] %@", ...`

Comment: Actually it seems to be working correctly now due to a bonehead move on my part.  I was looking for the problem in the wrong place.  But a follow-up question to your question, what exactly does declaring SELF accomplish?

Comment: You can use SELF in predicates something like this:
`[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF == %@", AKPsiMemberObject];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I feel silly.  My problem was actually setting my cell.textLabel.text = to the member object instead of the string in the object. Apparently I made this change by accident some time ago when first implementing the UISearchBar and just never noticed.

My predicate is actually working correctly now! Thanks for everyone that took the time to help me out.